# How to make program output whole words with Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have a text (e.g. `"All Java programmers program good programs."`)  and need to output all words which have `program` inside.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("program");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.start() + " " + extractWord(matcher.start(), text));
}
```

Can I write a `Pattern` which will whole find words such as "programmers" as `Matcher` result?

I wrote the `extractWord` method myself as:

```
public static String extractWord(int start, String line) {
    int n = 0;
    while (start + n < line.length()) {
        if (line.charAt(start + n) == ' ' || line.charAt(start + n) == '.') {
            break;
        } else {
            n++;
        }
    }
    return line.substring(start, start + n);
}
```

but I don't like to do so.

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution would consist of changing your regular expression to `\w*program\w*`. This will match any word containing `program` and any possible prefixes and suffixes made of word characters (i.e. letter, number and underscore). Then, use `matcher.group()` to retrieve the occurrences found by the matcher.

A more advanced approach would use the regular expression `[a-z]*program[a-z]*`. This will match any word containing `program` and any possible prefixes and suffixes made of only letters. The [`Pattern.CASE_INSENTITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag matches letters in both lower and upper cases.

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 856 bytes

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main
{
    public static final String simpleText = "All Java programmers program good programs.";
    public static final String complexText = "All Java deProGraMMers Program good pRoGrAmS.";

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Groups for '" + simpleText + "':");
        printGroups(simpleText);
        System.out.println("Groups for '" + complexText + "':");
        printGroups(complexText);
    }

    private static void printGroups(String text)
    {
        String regex = "[a-z]*program[a-z]*";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

Execution output:

```
 Groups for 'All Java programmers program good programs.':
 programmers
 program
 programs
 
 Groups for 'All Java deProGraMMers Program good pRoGrAmS.':
 deProGraMMers
 Program
 pRoGrAmS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVLRTsIwFH3fV9zshU2kH@DCAzGEYDJCHPGFEFO3OordurQdooZvn@3WsaGi9qXtvfec23N6d3iPR7wg@S55qSqaFVwo2OkgKhVlSJCUHFCIVbwlInAu5JdYKSLywHGK8onRGGKGpYQQ09z5cEAvG5cKK7090xwziJSgeQpSkzKyIgcFY3AnjMGdpodC8FTgLCNCtmdIOU/ai0Ru8Bd1zA314Rt3QpaCzwQOQ8O@PGO/14lJFhn2H@j3nCaQaV1e02K9ASxS6deljVSzojepSIZ4qVChyxTLPXcmeFlIeOYCBi4M@7qH4A5uXD844WtQA/C6ul7Bfxr01f/aoVdoK45Wu6B7rMiZ@D7Q2qwM8KsDTaqeD@P9Go/eN1f275qL273GDhAUdh@3EWTeRhnxaqLrU/h2Ek0f54touojmq/nDtKfMDqv@pWYft6zIRjx17uXrVjcAz2aRnqDE8/1TutN0wfgWmBpTNLJjPlozj1X1CQ)

Comment: 1) Question says *"words which have program **inside**"*. How about `deprogram`? --- 2) How about `Program`? --- 3) Why the capture group? You're not even using it. --- 4) Is `program_42` a word? In programming, it's an *identifier*, but is it a "word"?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your comments. I'll edit the answer addressing your points, but we may want to listen to OP's considerations.

Comment: Is [`CASE_INSENSITIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag not appropriate to include in your solution?

Comment: @Abra Yes, it is super appropriate, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

I would us something like this using the `String.contains()` method:

```
String str = "All Java programmers program good programs.";
String[] arr = str.split(" ");
for (String s : arr)
    if(s.contains("program"))
        System.out.println(s);

//output: 
//programmers
//program
//programs.
```

Comment: This does not use `Pattern` and `Matcher` as requested by OP.

Comment: Yes. The first answer is better

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka If it solves your problem, then please don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this regex:  `\b\w*program\w*\b`..

- `\b` -- means start with word boundary
- `\w*` -- means there can be 0 or more word character
- `program` -- match program
- `\w*` -- means there can be 0 or more word character
- `\b` -- means end with word boundary

code:

```
String text = "All Java programmers program good programs.";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w*program\\w*\\b");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```